# inet_ntop failing with "Address family not supported by protocol"

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having an issue with inet_ntop failing and setting errno to "Address family not supported by protocol".

Accept code:

```
    //Wait for connection from client
    Network.RemoteSock = accept(Network.LocalSock, (struct sockaddr *) &Network.RemoteAddr, &Network.RemoteAddr_Size);
    if(Network.RemoteSock == -1) {
        Die("accept Failed In Webserver: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    //Set socket send timeout
    if(setsockopt(Network.RemoteSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&Settings.Send_Timeout, sizeof(Settings.Send_Timeout)) == -1) {
        Die("setsockopt Failed In Webserver: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    //Set socket recv timeout
    if(setsockopt(Network.RemoteSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&Settings.Recv_Timeout, sizeof(Settings.Recv_Timeout)) == -1) {
        Die("setsockopt Failed In Webserver: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    //Get remote address
    if(inet_ntop(Network.RemoteAddr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *) &Network.RemoteAddr), Address, sizeof(Address)) == NULL) {
        Die("inet_ntop Failed In Webserver: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
```

Definition of Network:

```
struct _Network {
    int LocalSock, RemoteSock;
    struct sockaddr_storage RemoteAddr;
    socklen_t RemoteAddr_Size;
} Network;
```

Checking with GDB, I see that Network.RemoteAddr.ss_family is 0 before the call to inet_ntop:

```
(gdb) print Network.RemoteAddr
$1 = {ss_family = 0, __ss_align = 0, __ss_padding = '\000' <repeats 111 times>}
```

Not knowing what valid values for ss_family are, I don't know whether this means the accept call failed or not - But I suspect that's where the issue lies.

It'll probably be some stupid problem somewhere, but I just can't see it, any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
- Alex

Comment: If the `accept` fails or not is the return value. If it's `-1` then it failed, otherwise all went okay. But the address length you pass to `accept` have to be initialized before calling `accept`, have you done that?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, compilable testcase. Minimal means "using only enough code required to reproduce the problem". Compilable means "providing enough code for us to be able to compile and debug on our machines without guessing or fixing typos". Your current testcase fails on the "compilable" attribute.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ahh that was the issue, thanks very much. I must have missed the bit where you have to initialise before calling. I just thought it was filled out with the address size.

For anyone having this problem I fixed it like so:

        //Initialise address size

        Network.RemoteAddr_Size = sizeof(Network.RemoteAddr);